# How to create a Rock, Paper, Scissors program

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm very new to python and am taking an online class. I'm not very familiar with many functions in python so if you could keep it somewhat basic for me to keep track of, I would really appreciate it. I am trying to make a program that runs Rock, Paper, Scissors with a user but the num_games is not being accepted in the "for i in range". Also, I have run it and found that Scissors can beat Rock (THIS IS ANARCHY!). Can anyone assist me? Thanks in advance!

```
import random

def comp_turn():

    comp_move = random.randint(1,3)

    if comp_move == 1:
        return "Rock!"

    elif comp_move == 2:
        return "Paper!"

    else:
        return "Scissors!"

def main():

    num_games = int(input("Enter how many games you would like to play: "))

    print "You are going to play " + str(num_games) + " games! Here we go!"

    num_wins = 0

    for i in range(num_games):

        user_move = input("Choose either Rock, Paper or Scissors and enter it: ")

        cpu_turn = comp_turn()

        print "The computer went with: " + cpu_turn

        if user_move == 'Rock' and cpu_turn == 'Scissors':
            print "You won! Nice job!"
            num_wins +=1

        elif user_move == 'Paper' and cpu_turn == 'Rock':
            print "You won! Nice job!"
            num_wins +=1

        elif user_move == 'Scissors' and cpu_turn == 'Paper':
            print "You won! Nice job!"
            num_wins +=1

        elif user_move == cpu_turn:
            print "Oh! You tied"

        else:
            print "Whoops! You lost!"
            return num_wins

print main()
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: To compare what the computer came up with and what the user put in, seeing who won.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491776/logically-determine-game-outcome-with-formula/57494114#57494114.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want:

```
import random

def comp_turn():
   return random.choice(['Rock','Paper','Scissors'])
def main():
   num_games = int(input("Enter how many games you would like to play: "))
   print("You are going to play " + str(num_games) + " games! Here we go!")
   num_wins = 0
   for i in range(num_games):
      user_move = input("Choose either Rock, Paper or Scissors and enter it: ")
      cpu_turn = comp_turn()
      print("The computer went with: " + cpu_turn)
      if user_move == 'Rock' and cpu_turn == 'Scissors': print("You won! Nice job!"); num_wins +=1
      elif user_move == 'Paper' and cpu_turn == 'Rock': print("You won! Nice job!"); num_wins +=1
      elif user_move == 'Scissors' and cpu_turn == 'Paper': print("You won! Nice job!"); num_wins +=1
      elif user_move == cpu_turn: print("Oh! You tied")
      else: print("Whoops! You lost!");
   return num_wins
print(main())
```

Or even Better:

```
import random

def comp_turn():
   return random.choice(['Rock','Paper','Scissors'])
def main():
   num_games = int(input("Enter how many games you would like to play: "))
   print("You are going to play " + str(num_games) + " games! Here we go!")
   num_wins = 0
   winning=[('Rock','Scissors'),('Paper','Rock'),('Scissors','Paper')]
   for i in range(num_games):
      user_move = input("Choose either Rock, Paper or Scissors and enter it: ")
      cpu_turn = comp_turn()
      print("The computer went with: " + cpu_turn)
      if (user_move,cpu_turn) in winning:
         print('You won!')
         num_wins+=1
      elif user_move == cpu_turn:
         print('Same')
      else:
         print('You lost!')
   return num_wins
print(main())
```

And another option that's also good:

```
import random

def comp_turn():
   return random.choice(['Rock','Paper','Scissors'])
def main():
   num_games = int(input("Enter how many games you would like to play: "))
   print("You are going to play " + str(num_games) + " games! Here we go!")
   num_wins = 0
   d={}.fromkeys([('Rock','Scissors'),('Paper','Rock'),('Scissors','Paper')],'You Won')
   for i in range(num_games):
      user_move = input("Choose either Rock, Paper or Scissors and enter it: ")
      cpu_turn = comp_turn()
      print("The computer went with: " + cpu_turn)
      if not user_move == cpu_turn:
         print(d.get((user_move,cpu_turn),'You lost!'))
      else:
         print('Same')
   return num_wins
print(main())
```

Comment: That looks very nice but the goal of the program was to use numbers associated with Rock, paper and scissors. I will keep the .choice option in mind for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want:

```
import random

outcome = random.choice(['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'])
print(outcome)
```

Comment: Might as well use `random.sample`, that's what it's made for.

Comment: Well, `random.choice` would actually be the method to go for. In any case, answer updated.

Comment: The required option is to use numbers associated with Rock, paper and scissors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the '!' in the *comp_turn* function? It seems like *cpu_turn* variable will contain either 'Rock!', 'Scissors!' or 'Paper!' while your if-else condition is looking for either 'Rock', 'Scissors' or 'Paper' without the '!'. So, no matter what the player or cpu chooses, it will go into 'else' in the 'for' loop and the player loses.

This is the edited code:

```
import random

def comp_turn():
    comp_move = random.randint(1,3)
    if comp_move == 1: return "Rock"
    elif comp_move == 2: return "Paper"
    else: return "Scissors"

def main():
    num_games = int(input("Enter how many games you would like to play: "))
    print("You are going to play " + str(num_games) + " games! Here we go!")
    num_wins = 0
    for i in range(num_games):
        user_move = input("Choose either Rock, Paper or Scissors and enter it: ")
        cpu_turn = comp_turn()
        print("The computer went with: " + cpu_turn)
        if user_move == 'Rock' and cpu_turn == 'Scissors':
            print("You won! Nice job!")
            num_wins +=1
        elif user_move == 'Paper' and cpu_turn == 'Rock':
            print("You won! Nice job!")
            num_wins +=1
        elif user_move == 'Scissors' and cpu_turn == 'Paper':
            print("You won! Nice job!")
            num_wins +=1
        elif user_move == cpu_turn:
            print("Oh! You tied")
        else: print("Whoops! You lost!")
    return num_wins
print(main())
```

Do note that the player's input is case sensitive too. Hope this helps!