# Logically determine game outcome with formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, formula

I am trying to become a better coder, which includes getting rid of my 'hard-coding' habits to keep my programs dynamic and easy to maintain.

Right now I am writing a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game as practice:

```
import time

validoptions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

u1input = input("User 1, do you want to choose rock, paper or scissors?").lower()
if not u1input in(validoptions):
    u1input = input("What the hell User 1, choose a valid option: rock, paper or scissors?").lower()
u2input = input("User 2, do you want to choose rock, paper or scissors?").lower()
if not u2input in(validoptions):
    u2input = input("What the hell User 2, choose a valid option: rock, paper or scissors?").lower()

u1 = validoptions.index(u1input)
u2 = validoptions.index(u2input)

if u1 - u2 == 0:
    result = "It's a draw! Both parties have proven to be of equal strength."


print("Stakes are high... The battle is on... Calculating losses...")
for i in range(1,4):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("...")

time.sleep(1)
print(result)
```

For such a game like Rock, Paper, Scissors, there aren't many outcomes (6 wins/losses, and 1 draw outcome, or 3^2 individual outcomes). I could easily code all possible outcomes next to the draw outcome I have already coded. However, what if the game expands with 3 more options? Say: `Rock, Paper, Scissors, Pans, Swords, and Rifles`: that would be 6^2 = 36 outcomes!

As this list expands, the amount of potential outcomes becomes harder to hard-code. I want to use a formula or another 'smart', dynamic method of determining the game's outcome, in a similar fashion to the `if u1 - u2 == 0:` line.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: If any user introduces an invalid value 2 times in a row, you'll get exceptions. Also, if there isn't a draw, you'll get an exception. I don't understand your outcomes count: there can be 3: one player wins, or draw. There's no point in adding more values for just 2 players.

Comment: Good call on the consecutive invalid values, but your comment about there not being a draw is futile.. That is what this entire question is about. There are more than 3 outcomes, albeit they fall under those three categories. Those categories need to be defined on basis of the outcomes though! @CristiFati

Comment: Which comment? "*if there isn't a draw, you'll get an exception*"?

Comment: @CristiFati *" I could easily code all possible outcomes next to the draw outcome I have already coded. However, what if the game expands with 3 more options?"*. I am well aware the code does not handle wins/losses yet, that is the purpose of this question

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. What is the goal of the question? Based on 2 given inputs to determine the outcome of the game or to list every possible outcome (based on all possible inputs that 2 players might input)?

Comment: The former. Hard-coding would be like `If player1 chose A and player2 chose B then...` for each possible outcome. However, this would require a tonne of work if this game had not 3 but, say, 100 options to choose from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I initially thought about the ***R**ock–**P**aper–**S**cissors* (*RPS*) rules:

- It's a cyclic relation between the elements where each element beats the one in before it (*Scissors* beats (cuts) *Paper*)

  - The 1<sup>st</sup> element (that doesn't have anything before) beats the last one (and the cycle is complete)
- When adding more elements, it would only be to allow more users to play (as long as the user count is smaller by ***1*** than the element count), but now I see that **it's wrong** as there are cases when the outcome can be undefined (actually the only working case is when there are no 2 players that selected the same option)

Apparently (thanks to [[Wikipedia]: Rock–paper–scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock%E2%80%93paper%E2%80%93scissors)), for a **balanced** game (odd number of elements):

- Each element beats half of the other ones (and as a consequence, loses to the other half)

  - The (1<sup>st</sup>) one before it
  - The 3<sup>rd</sup> one before it
  - The 5<sup>th</sup> one before it
  - ...
  - When reaching beginning of the list, jump to its end (*wrap-around*)

  This is a generalization of the 3 element (*RPS*) game (and also applies to *RPSLS*)

Here's what the above rule looks like when put into code (I've also redesigned it to correct some errors in your snippet). All the "magic" happens in *outcome*.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


_elements_list = [
    ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"],
    ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Spock", "Lizard"],  # !!! The order is DIFFERENT (RPSSL) than the name of the game: RPSLS !!!
]

elements_dict = {len(item): item for item in _elements_list}
del _elements_list


def get_users_choices(valid_options):
    ret = [-1] * 2
    for i in (0, 1):
        user_choice = None
        while user_choice not in valid_options:
            user_choice = input("Enter user {0:d} option (out of {1:}): ".format(i + 1, valid_options))
        ret[i] = valid_options.index(user_choice)
    return ret


def outcome(idx0, idx1, count):  # Returns -1 when 1st player wins, 0 on draw and 1 when 2nd player wins
    if idx0 == idx1:
        return 0
    index_steps = [-i * 2 - 1 for i in range(count // 2)]  # Index steps (n // 2 items) from current index: {-1, -3, -5, ...} (negative values mean: before)
    idx0_beat_idxes = [(idx0 + i + count) % count for i in index_steps]  # Wrap around when reaching the beginning of the list
    if idx1 in idx0_beat_idxes:
        return -1
    return 1


def main():
    element_count = 3  # Change it to 5 for RPSLS
    if element_count <= 2:
        raise ValueError("Can't play game")
    elements = elements_dict.get(element_count)
    if not elements:
        raise ValueError("Invalid option count")
    choices = get_users_choices(elements)
    res = outcome(*choices, element_count)
    if res == 0:
        print("'{0:s}' and '{1:s}' are DRAW.".format(elements[choices[0]], elements[choices[1]]))
    elif res < 0:
        print("'{0:s}' WINS over '{1:s}'.".format(elements[choices[0]], elements[choices[1]]))
    else:
        print("'{0:s}' LOSES to '{1:s}'.".format(elements[choices[0]], elements[choices[1]]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057491776]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Enter user 1 option (out of ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']): Rock
> Enter user 2 option (out of ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']): Scissors
> 'Rock' WINS over 'Scissors'.
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: This is taking some time to digest... Coming from VBA, Python is a lot more abstract

Comment: Play with it (run it) several times. As I said the logic is in *outcome*. Most of the code is for user input validation, output formatting and so on. I agree, it looks complex if not used to the language. Feel free to ask any question (unfortunately, I don't know how to move them directly to chat).

Comment: I can read most of the code, but I am having a hard time understanding the code populating `index_steps` and `idx0_beat_idxes` in the `outcome` UDF

Comment: *index\_steps* will contain `[-1, -3, -5, .....]` it will go till it will have `n // 2` elements, and *idx0\_beat\_idxes* will contain the indexes that *idx0* beats `[idx0 - 1, idx0 - 3, ...]`. The `count) % count` is a trick (I could have written it differently - using an *if* - only adding *count* when the sum before it would be negative) to always have positive indexes (to wrap around the end of list when reaching its beginning).  Adding `print(index_steps)` and `print(idx0_beat_idxes)` would probably clear things up.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `idx0_beat_idxes` holds a list of all elements offset by n (with stored in the `index_steps` list) from the chosen element by player 1?

Comment: That is correct. Those are the (indexes of) options that are beaten by player 1's option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197939/discussion-between-cristifati-and-tim-stack).

Answer (score 1):

This is really cool! So, I think I would use a dictionary to control what loses to what:

```
dict_loss = dict()
dict_loss['paper']='scissors'
dict_loss['scissors']='rock'
dict_loss['rock']='paper'
```

Then the players make a choice and you just check if their choices fall into the dictionaries:

```
player_1='paper'
player_2='rock'

if player_2 in dict_loss[player_1]:
    print("Player 2 Wins")
else:
    if player_1 in dict_loss[player_2]:
        print("Player 1 Wins")
    else:
        print("DRAW")
```

You can extend the dictionary with the new objects you get, I'm not sure how Pans, swords and riffles work, but you can do:

```
dict_loss['paper']=['scissors', 'riffle']
```

if paper loses to riffles, and so on...

Hope this helps, if you have any "data structure" restrictions let me know and I will try to think of something different.

Comment: Although this would be less work than coding all outcomes, this still requires a complete dictionary of all possible outcomes. Imagine a Rock, Paper, Scissors game with 100 options. The size of the dictionary would be considerably large and it would require an excessive amount of work to code

Comment: @TimStack I agree that it would escalate, but it would be very different from the first option of coding all possible combinations. While in your approach for every new addition you get a factorial increase for mine it is an extra line. Since the game is not logical it is hard to come up with a formula for it.

Comment: @TimStack, Based on erdelyia's idea, I think that if you properly organize the words in the valid_options in a way that index_of_word - X = win you could use only the validoptions variable.

Answer (score 1):

List is a good idea. In your case `validoptions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]` you can see, everything beats the only one before it (the `"paper"` beats the `"rock"`, the `"rock"` beats the `"scissors"` and the `"scissors"` beats the `"paper"`. So if you sort it that way, it is solvable with the use of the indexes only. If you want to increase the choices, you can, but tke care, only the odd numbers will provide fair game.

In general if you make a list of `options`, with a length of `length`, then:

```
if u1 == u2:
    #it is a draw
elif u2input in validoptions[u1 - int((length-1)/2):u1]:
    #player1 has won
else:
    #player2 has won
```

Comment: Not everything beats the one before, scissors do not beat rock.

Comment: My bad, i left the sentence unfinished. Will correct

Comment: Being still a novice to Python, I can't quite get this to work.. `is in` is invalid syntax and printing `print(validoptions[u1 - (len(validoptions)-1)/2:u1])` returns a TypeError saying *slice indices must be integers...*

Comment: Just have to cast the `(length-1)/2` to `int`. Corrected.

Comment: *"only the odd numbers will provide fair game"* why would this be?

Comment: Because if you choose `option_x`, and you can beat `n` option, then you have to be beaten by other `n` option. That is `2n` option and your own one. And the number `2n + 1` will always be odd.

Comment: There is always one order, where every item beats n items before it and gets beaten by n items behind it (and all valid permutations). So this approach will generally work. (Look for example on "the big bang theory" shirts with rock, paper, scissors, lizzard, spock; there's even a graph on them that shows this order)

Comment: That is an interesting approach I had not taken in mind. While the original game follows a circular method, this is much more complicated. A circular method could work with `elif u2 == u1 - 1`

Comment: I still can't seem to comprehend that line, it's only throwing syntax errors at me. `elif u2 is in validoptions[u1 - int((len(validoptions)-1)/2):u1]:` is not accepted because of `is in`. Care to explain the idea of this line?

Comment: With the list[start:stop] (called slicing) you can take a sublist from the original list. I took the sublist that is before the `index1` so the ones thoose are beaten by that. And if the `index2` is in that sublist then the player1 has won.

Comment: In that case, should it not be `elif u2 in(...)`?

Comment: Yeah probably, and you should check the `u2input` instead of `u2`

Comment: that's true. current line that's working is `elif u2input in validoptions[u1 - int((len(validoptions)-1)/2):u1]:`

Comment: In Python you can index a list from -length to +(length-1). In your original case `validoptions[-2]` means "paper". That is why you can easily substract thoose two indexes, and yet you will not leave the range given earlier. I have used that mechanism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197928/discussion-between-tim-stack-and-erdelyia).

Answer (score 1):

As the rules are not clearly defined, it is not trivial to give a one-size-fits-all-solution. I would probably assume there is some cyclic definition if "win/lose", giving me modulo-calculus such as e.g.:

```py
winner = ["None", "Player 1", "Player 2"]
win_index = (u1 - u2) % len(validoptions)
print("Winner: " + winner[win_index])
```

Perhaps it is also interesting to take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock%E2%80%93paper%E2%80%93scissors#Additional_weapons.